# ViewPager - customizing title PagerTabStrip

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I used title in ViewPager like on the screen below : just a text with a android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip

in `OnPageChangeListener()`  I use method  `public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position)` and it sets title

[image]

is there any way to customize that field to look like this :

[image]

may be some kind of custom adapter for title?

Comment: I has a similar question. Did you find any other way than these answers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can easily add a icon/drawable to the PageTabStrip using SpannableString or SpannableStringBuilder.

For example, to display an icon before the text :

```
Drawable myDrawable; //Drawable you want to display

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

SpannableStringBuilder sb = new SpannableStringBuilder(" " + "Page #"+ position); // space added before text for convenience

myDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, myDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), myDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight()); 
ImageSpan span = new ImageSpan(myDrawable, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE); 
sb.setSpan(span, 0, 1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE); 

return sb;
}
```

Comment: it's closest, but still result is not same

Answer (score 4):

This library gives you much more customization options than support library's PagerTabStrip:
https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip